# Moving UMI from tag into read name

Tags: sam, umi

I have a bam file with Unique Molecular Identifiers (UMIs) for each read present on the RX tag ( such as `RX:Z:TGAGAAGGG`), as expected by picard and fgbio tools.

However, several other tools (such as UMI-tools) expect the UMIs to be present at the end of the read name, such as (`NB501943:73:HK333BGXC:3:12402:20313:16437_TGAGAAGGG`).

Does anyone know of a tool to do this?
I have an `awk` solution which I'll self-answer with, but I don't know whether that is robust.

Comment: Did you check UMI-tools, this is afaik exactly what it is doing?

Comment: @ATpoint, unless I'm incorrect, UMI-tools can't do this directly. `umi_tools extract` moves sequences from a position in the FASTA sequence onto the read name, but in this case the reads have been added to a tag via `fgbio`.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is (`awk` is not a tool I'm very familiar with, so this may not be good `awk` code, there is presumably a way to get it to print the header lines unmodified.):

```
samtools view -H temp.sam > temp2.sam
samtools view temp.sam | 
awk '{OFS = "\t"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  if ($i ~ /^RX:Z:/) {$1=$1"_"$i; gsub("RX:Z:","",$1); print}}' >> temp2.sam
```

This seems to work when I test it, but I don't know if I'm missing anything.